# Can't log in Opensis after installation

Tags: installation, xampp, solution

I am using Mac and XAMPP including php 7.1.10 (Apache + MariaDB + PHP + Perl)

I installed Opensis 6.4 successfully. Database was created. I made a staff id. school id was created too. the information is well connected in database.

But it keep asking me to install opensis. I cann't get log in page.

How can I solve the problem?

I tried 6.3 version and 5.3 version of Opensis

Answer (score 0):

Do a fresh install of XAMPP for OSX  Copy opensis (I used Community
  Edition) to the htdocs directory Before you start SQL and Apache, do
  the following in Terminal:

```
sudo chown -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opensis
sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/opensis
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but it doesn't work. it repeats installation.